# fscanf only reads some chars

Tags: c, char, integer, scanf

I need to read a mixture of chars and ints from a txt file in C. The text file has 1 line and reads:

```
sarah (z) murphy 1 biology d 67
```

This is meant to represent:

> 'name' 'initial' 'surname' 'year' 'course' 'group' 'average'

My code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

   FILE *fptr = fopen("test1.txt", "r"); // declare file pointer and open the file to 'read only'


   //create variables to hold the values
   char firstn[10], initial[3], secondn[10], course[10], group[1];
   int year=0, average=0; //initialize at 0 

   // in case the file isn't found (returns NULL if it doesn't exist), exit the program
   if(!fptr){
      printf("File not found... Exiting program \n");
      exit(1);
   }

   fscanf(fptr, "%s %s %s %d %s %s %d", firstn, initial, secondn, &year, course, group, &average); //read and assign to each variable
   

   printf("here %s, %s, %s, %d, %s, %s, %d \n", firstn, initial, secondn, year, course, group, average); //print to show new variables

   fclose(fptr); //close the file
   return 0;
}
```

I can't figure out why not every variable prints. The result I'm getting looks like this:

```
  , (z), murphy, 1, , d, 67
```

I expect it to look like:

```
  sarah, (z), murphy, 1, biology, d, 67
```

Why are both 'name' and 'course' appearing to be empty?

Comment: Your char arrays aren't big enough. `initial[3]` is only big enough for 2 characters, because you need room for the null terminator.

Comment: `group[1]` can't hold anything, because it only has room for the null terminator.

Comment: So you're overflowing and causing undefined behavior.

Comment: Thank you! This fixed it for me. Makes a lot of sense now.